# How to make regular expression match whole word or nothing

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string and I am trying to match the whole string or nothing. If I put an unwanted character ex. `'?'`, the regex still matches everything up until the `'?'`

The ragex is only supposed to accept `alphanumeric, =, _, -, /, +`

Regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9=_\/+-]+
```

Inupt:

```
M7ss6vk9OS+J5EMhjeh0JGq7bD3sM9M6cX+WXRUkxnx1x9M1euL9H3x1bLpqtn1Q7NOviGCTMx2uG47AcVt3C178bjoivF+lDBlhgieX9aaRcCdl3Zuo1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add a `$` at the end of your regex.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9=_\/+-]+$
```

Comment: it doesn't match anything if I add the $

Comment: How are you using this regex?

Comment: well for now I am checking on regexr.com

Comment: Regexr doesn't seem to be applying the expression correctly. I just ran it through javascript and it works fine.

Comment: Try it here (it's in beta, but the match on the bottom of the page strictly uses the regex you have) http://christopherbauer.github.io/RegExplainer/

Comment: I got it, for some reason, that input string is incorrect, maybe has some special characters?

Comment: Go to the "flags" selection (in the blue bar) on regexr and check off multiline.

Answer (score 1):

To tie the end of your regex to the end of your string, add `$` at the end of the expression. This is similar to adding `^` at the beginning of regex to tie the beginning of your regex to the beginning of string.

So it becomes `^[a-zA-Z0-9=_\/+-]+$`.

Comment: it doesn't match anythign if I add the $

Comment: @User456789, how do you invoke the regex match in your program? Are you sure that your string has no spaces nor \n at the end?